# configure postfix to catch all email for all domain and forward to local user

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I'd like to configure Postfix (on Ubuntu) to catch all email for all domain and store them locally.

I'd use it for testing. The application under test sends emails to random addresses (abc@abc.com, def@other.tv, and so on), and I'd like to check these emails locally (thunderbird).

I already now that the following in main.cf forwards **anyuser@mydestination** to localuser:

```
local_recipient_maps=
luser_relay = localuser
```

But I'd like to forward **anyuser@anydomain** to localuser too.

What is the simplest Postfix configuration for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found another configuration which works: specifying "mydestination" as a regexp table which accepts any domain.

Main.cf:

```
local_recipient_maps=
luser_relay = riskop
mydestination = regexp:/etc/postfix/match_all_destination_re
```

match_all_destination_re (// matches everything, result is irrelevant):

```
// this_can_be_anything
```

I consider this solution more straightforward than Esa's "Overriding Postfix's built-in default transport:nexthop" solution.

Note that instead of the "regexp" table format you can use perl-compatible "pcre" format table also. That may result better performance (which is absolutely no concern in my use case). In that case, however you need pcre  support in Postfix. The config in this case:

Main.cf:

```
local_recipient_maps=
luser_relay = riskop
mydestination = pcre:/etc/postfix/match_all_destination_re
```

match_all_destination_pcre (// matches everything, result is irrelevant):

```
// this_can_be_anything
```

Comment: Nice! This requires that Postfix is built with [PCRE Support](http://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html) and the amount of configuration lines is equal.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good start! While there might be other ways, I'll continue from where you have started, i.e.

```
local_recipient_maps =
luser_relay = localuser
```

In this sitation you only need to make all domais handled as if they were in `$mydestination`.

Overriding Postfix's built-in default `transport:nexthop` selection is possible by using [transport](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) maps:

> `transport_maps` (default: empty)
>
> Optional lookup tables with mappings from recipient address to
>   (message delivery transport, next-hop destination). See [transport(5)](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html)
>   for details.
>
> Specify zero or more `type:table` lookup tables, separated by
>   whitespace or comma. Tables will be searched in the specified order
>   until a match is found. If you use this feature with local files, run
>   `postmap /etc/postfix/transport` after making a change.

In your `main.cf`, add `transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport`.

In `/etc/postfix/transport` you combine these two:

- `local_transport` (default: `local:$myhostname`)

  > This is the default for final delivery to  domains  listed  with
  >   `mydestination`,  and  for  `[ipaddress]`  destinations  that  match
  >   `$inet_interfaces` or `$proxy_interfaces`. 
  >   The default nexthop  destination is the MTA hostname.
- `* transport:nexthop`

  > The special pattern `*` represents any address (i.e. it  functions
  >   as  the  wildcard  pattern,  and is unique to Postfix transport tables).

Resulting: `*    local:$myhostname`

Please keep this unconventional configuration inside your lab.